# How to make an HTTP/CSS Checkbox Slider to work properly?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, slider

I'll be glad if you can help me.
I was required to develop a checkbox slider.

The issue is that when I click on the Slider I need that 2 things will happen:

1. When the slider block is on left, the "Specific" word will be hidden
   and will be shown only after clicking the block which will turn to 
   the right side.
2. That the sliding will be in an animation.

Here's the code:

```
HTML:
=====
<div class="checkboxThree">
   <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="checkboxThreeInput" name="" />
   <label for="checkboxThreeInput"></label>
</div>

CSS:
====
/**
 * Checkbox Three
 */
.checkboxThree {
    width: 95px;
    height: 16px;
    background:#A22452;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

    /**
     * Create the text for the "All" position
     */
    .checkboxThree:before {
      content: 'All';
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: 70px;
      height: 2px;
      color: #F9F9F9;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    /**
     * Create the label for the "Specific" position
     */
    .checkboxThree:after {
       content: 'Specific';
       position: absolute;
       top: -1px;
       left: 4px;
       height: 2px;
       color: #F7A6F4;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
       font-weight: bold;
    }

    /**
     * Create the pill to click
     */
    .checkboxThree label {
        display: block;
        width: 32px;
        height: 14px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition: all .5s ease;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        z-index: 1;
        /* left: 12px; */
        background: #08EFEF;

    }

    /**
     * Create the checkbox event for the label
     */
    .checkboxThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        left: 62px;

    }

link: https://jsfiddle.net/gtq792sa/
```

Can you please show me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) is a nice answer. It comes down to having  a label with an input type="slider" inside it, and lots of css styling.